# SharePoint 2013 list webform - error 5566

Tags: infopath, forms-authentication

I've been struggling with this for past couple of weeks researching all over.

I have a webform with couple of views with one being restricted to certain users. When I try and query the data using SOAP, I'll get

> 5566 error

. I found out that it's because of the `authentication` - it tries to receive the data using anonymous user (IUSR) rather then the logged in user.

So my question is, how can I go around it or change it so it queries it correctly?

I used [this](http://claytoncobb.com/2009/07/19/infopath-user-roles-in-browser-enabled-forms-using-groups/) method and even go through their suggestions but their answers applied to load balancing and random errors, not continuous or SP2013

PS I'm new here but this place rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by asking Google differently on [SharePoint Rocks blog](https://sharepointrocks.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/sharepoint-2013-using-infopath-and-userprofileservice-asmx-with-claims-based-web-applications/)

So yes, the problem is the authentication however when you disable anonymous access directly on IIS it'll break SharePoint as it needs it. The credentials are passed via process impersonation and all you need is to change AllowAnonymousImpersonation from true to false

1. go to IIS that runs your SP
2. find its address and right click -> explore
3. open web.config in your text editor and locate AllowAnonymousImpersonation
4. change it from true to false
5. restart IIS

This will now stop the 5566 error from occuring.

Then to get the actual data values I followed [this post](http://thinketg.com/using-infopath-and-the-web-service-getuserprofilebyname/) as you need to create a rule to read the actual value but that was not my original question so I won't be going into details.